# Why is unity compressing my button image so much?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, image-compression

I want to make a simple button in unity with an image. The image is a 800x800 png and looks fine when i open it in any image viewer. When i place the image in a asset folder and add it to my button however, it looks awful! It is supposed to look like this:

[image: High quality sudoku board]

Instead it turns out like this:

[image: Very low quality sudoku board]

Here is the inspection menu for the image:

[image: Inspection image for the sudoku image]

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Is it inside the editor or in the build? What size is your button?

Comment: Try setting your pixels per unit to 100. Try generating mipmap on advanced tab if your sprite will have less pixels on screen than the texture resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the **Filter Mode** to **Point** should fix this

[image]

---

If the above method doesn't work, try tweaking **Max Size** and set **Compression** to **None**

[image]

Comment: Still dont work as intended. Tried every Max size and set my filter to point.